# LINQ: How to join nested Lists in an ObjectCollection

Tags: sql, linq, nested-lists

is it possible to define a LINQ statement for the following problems WITHOUT using a foreach loop?

```
public class GroupObject
{
    public String name;
    public List<String> letters;

    public void test()
    {
        List<GroupObject> myGroups = new List<GroupObject> {
            new GroupObject {
                name="test1",
                letters=new List<String>{"x","y","z"}
            },
            new GroupObject {
                name="test2",
                letters=new List<String>{"l","m","n"}
            },
            new GroupObject {
                name="test3",
                letters=new List<String>{"m","x","z"}
            }
        };

        // LINQ problem 1: how to get a list of all 9 letters
        // List<string> allLetters = (from ...).ToList();

        // LINQ problem 2: how to get a list of all 6 DISTINCT letters
        // List<string> allDistictLetters = (from ...).ToList();
    }
}
```

While writing this question, I found a solution to the problems. I will still post (and answer) the question, since this one was a real bugger for me. And I did not find a suitable existing question here.

Ciao,
Juve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this problem can be solved by `SelectMany` and `Distinct`!

```
var allLetters = myGroups.SelectMany(go => go.letters);
var allUniqueLetters = allLetters.Distinct();
```

The second variable name is misleading tho. It will return, among other letters, one instance of `"m"`, which was *not* unique in the original collection ;)

Comment: Wow, you were really fast! I'll try that.

Comment: Works perfect! And it's much shorter than my solution. Even if it might be more cryptic for people who do not understand lambda.
Thx very much!

Comment: @Juve: you're welcome. i find that `from ...` selectors quickly become *extremely* cryptic when they get a little more complicated than this. and if this prompts the reader to go ahead and learn how lambda works in C#, you will have helped them tremendously ;)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, I found the answer myself:

```
List<string> allLetters = (from g in myGroups from l in g.letters select l).ToList();
List<string> allDistinctLetters = allLetters.Distinct().ToList();
```

I hope this helpful for somebody.

Ciao, Juve