# LINQ nested (inner) JOIN does not join children

Tags: c#, linq, join, nested

Being rather new to LINQ, I am probably not looking for the correct search terms, that's why I am asking here.

I have a data transfer object (DTO) for the current timestep and a DTO for the previous timestep. I am intending to JOIN this information into a single (nested) list and display procentual changes (for all entries of the list). The nested contains nodes of type `myObject`. In other words, the list consists of a couple of parent entries and (different levels of) child elements of the same type. The merging step towards `dataFullDto` works perfectly for the parent entries only, for the child entries, the destination object does not contain the information of the previous timestep, `PreviousValue` and `DeltaPercentage` are `null`. **Is it possible to perform that action on *all* nodes of a nested list without a foreach loop?**

Assume that there is a function `inputData(int timestep)` which gives back all the required data. I inherited the following code which contains a [LINQ inner JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins):

```cs
var dataCurrentDto = inputData(time).GroupBy(x => x.Position) // Position just contains .Id and .Name
    .Select(x => new myObject {
       PositionId = x.Key?.Id,
       PositionName = x.Key?.Name,
       children = x.Select(Mapper.Map<myObjectDto>),
       Value = x.Sum(y => y.Value),
       PreviousValue = 0, // just to initialize, to be overwritten asap
       DeltaPercentage = 0, // dito
    });
var dataPreviousDto = inputData.Select(time-1).GroupBy(x => x.Position)
    .Select(x => new myObject {
        PositionId = x.Key?.Id,   
        PositionName = x.Key?.Name,
        children = x.Select(Mapper.Map<myObjectDto>),
        Value = x.Sum(y => y.Value),
    });   
dataFullDto = from current in dataCurrentDto join previous in dataPrevious on
              new { current.PositionId, current.SubPositionId }
              equals new { previous.PositionId, previous.SubPositionId }
              select new myObjectDto {
                 PositionId = current.PositionId,
                 PositionName = current.PositionName,
                 children = current.children,
                 SubPositionId = current.SubPositionId,
                 SubPositionName = current.SubPositionName,
                 Value = current.Value,
                 PreviousValueAdjusted = previous.Value,
                 DeltaPercentage = (previous.!= null || previous.Value != 0) ?
                                   (current.Value - previous.Value) / previous.Value : null,
             };
```

I assume the `GroupBy()` was added to enable the sum over the children. But apparently, the sum over a [leave node](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeLeaf.html) does not simply give back the value of the property itself?

The DTO is defined as follows:

```
namespace API.Models
{
    public class myObjectDto
    {
        public int? PositionId { get; set; }
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public int SubPositionId { get; set; }
        public string SubPositionName { get; set; }
        public decimal? Value { get; set; }
        public decimal? PreviousValue { get; set; }
        public decimal? DeltaPercentage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The parent entries have `SubPositionId = null` and `SubPositionName = null`, the child entries have those two fields filled. Leaf-nodes have `children=null`.

#### References

- [LINQ: How to join nested Lists in an ObjectCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263690/linq-how-to-join-nested-lists-in-an-objectcollection)
- [LINQ inner join for nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820398/linq-inner-join-for-nested-list)
- [LINQ JOIN Child Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417913/linq-join-child-collection)

Comment: Maybe you just look for "SelectMany" ? This converts a List of List, to a 'flat' list.
The term "merging" is not defined in SQL or LINQ. And I don't understand the rest of your task.

Comment: @Holger: I want to keep the list's nested structure.

Comment: Linq will not recursively go through your tree.  You will need to write a recursive method to get grandchildren and other descendants.  You are only getting the first level children.  Should myObjectDto contain the children?   Or is that the

Comment: @jdweng So I have to explicitly loop over all children, even when they are first generation?

Comment: @B-rian. It's not destroyed, if you say you want to merge something, you want to create something new, out of the old -without destroying the old. The job you want to do, and the ideas you had for your solution, are hard to seperate in your question.

Comment: Look at the table where they are located.   A database is a flat table (Entity).  So to how hierarchy you will normally have a column for Parent Id or Child ID and the query will show all nodes.  Then to create a tree you will need a set of classes that contain contain hierarchy.  If you start with a tree then you have to transverse the tree and create a flat table with Parent/Child ID.

Comment: @Holger I will edit the question tonight as I am afk. The idea in brief: The goal is a nested list of the current timestep with `PositionId`, `PositionName`, `SubPositionId`, `SubPositionName`, `Value`, `PreviousValue`, and `DeltaPercentage` for all list entries. The last two fields are added from the previous month. The parent entries should have a `Value` which is the sum over all its children. A family (a parent & their children) all have the same `PositionId` and `PositionName`. Hope that this makes it clearer.

Comment: No, you just mix up too many topics, Joins, and Groups and Sums and List-flatening. If you do have a solution that works, it would be easier to understand.
You said, you have one with foreach- but you don't want to use foreach.
So present your bad but working solution, then we can improve it. (Might be better on CodeReview, cause this is not of common interest).

Comment: @Holger I posted all I have so far, what others have implemented. My colleagues said that I do not need foreach, that's why I am asking.

Comment: It sounds , like you do have an implementation with foreach, if you don't have any, it's meaningless to state "don't use foreach". You can also say "don't use a screw driver". We do not even know,whether your code is working or not. You talk about trouble in a Sum, that is 5th line `Value = x.Sum(y => y.Value),` first query. Why do you blow up your question with 50 more lines of code, if the trouble is already in line 5 ? Yes, you assume right, The `Sum` works only behind a `GroupBy`. Was this your question ? I cannot really see any question.